# Tkinter центрирование окна

Tags: python, tkinter

Имеется некоторый код:

```
root = Tk()
x = (self.root.winfo_screenwidth() - self.root.winfo_reqwidth()) / 2
y = (self.root.winfo_screenheight() - self.root.winfo_reqheight()) / 2
self.root.wm_geometry("+%d+%d" % (x, y))
```

Который в теории должен центрировать окно Tkinter. Однако этого не происходит (вернее происходит, но не совсем по центру, что неприемлемо). Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно [`tk::PlaceWindow`](http://wiki.tcl.tk/1254) использовать, чтобы отцентрировать окно верхнего уровня:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import tkinter

root = tkinter.Tk()
tkinter.Label(root, text='По Центру', font=('bold', 40)).pack()
# center window
root.eval('tk::PlaceWindow %s center' % root.winfo_pathname(root.winfo_id()))
root.mainloop()
```

Если вы хотите руками координаты положения окна подсчитать, то убедитесь что окно обновлено (`.update_idletasks()`) и только потом настраивайте геометрию (`f'{width}x{height}+{x}+{y}'`). См. [How to center a window on the screen in Tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3352918/4279)

Answer (score 1):

Знаете что попробуйте вот-так вот

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
x = (root.winfo_screenwidth() - root.winfo_reqwidth()) / 2
y = (root.winfo_screenheight() - root.winfo_reqheight()) / 2
root.wm_geometry("+%d+%d" % (x, y))
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: это копия кода из вопроса

Comment: @FotonPC, а `root.mainloop()` может на что-то влиять?